# How to redirect to another page in vanilla JavaScript on submitting HTML form with Django backend?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, forms

I have just started working on Django. What I need is to link a js file to my HTML file with a form and save form data. Then go to next screen, click a picture and POST the form data along with the picture.
I have linked the JS file. I have created an input type button instead of submit as I wanted to use JS.
My use case is of register and login. The first page to open is login then on clicking signup button I am taken to register page where I want the functionality that after user fills form and submits he is taken to face capture page.
I am not able to redirect to capture face page from JavaScript. I am using Vanilla JS.

When I am using `window.location.href = "camera_capture.html"` all I am getting is a url appended to the current url and no change in the current page. Something like

> register/capture_face.html

Is there a way I can do what I am trying to achieve and is it a good method to do it like this? or is there a better way I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and thank you everyone for you answers and time. I had to make some changes to make it work. Also thanks to @Minia for his help.
Instead of passing `filename.html` to `window.location.href`, I passed just the `path_name`. Then I created a url in my urls.py file in python and linked it to a view. Then in that view I rendered the html page I wanted to go to.
As @Minia mentioned I used "/" also in window.location.href that helped me.
I think it was a right approach too. If anyone is stuck like me I hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should instead use:

```
window.location.replace("/camera_capture.html")
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for reply but it didn't work. same result.

Comment: Try with the ```/``` before.

And do you use a ```e.preventdefault()``` somewhere ?

Comment: No I don't use e.preventdefault(). After using '/' as you mentioned, now I am getting Page Not Found 
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/camera_capture.html

Comment: I haven't tested this, but you could try using window.location.replace("./camera_capture.html");

Comment: You are getting Page Not Found, but what was the link in the search bar?

Comment: The link was the one appended to register @Minia. However I have made some changes and now it is working fine. I will put what i have done in an answer.